# java springboot: create an entity from the database in intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, entity

Beginner with java, I try to create an entity from a table of my database in intellij. I do this with the jetbrain documentation:

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/generating-code.html#generating_java_entities

the problem is that the entity created does not have annotations.

Here is the result when I respect the jetbrain documentation in my project:

```
public class Fiche {

  private long id;
  private String type;
  private String url;

  
  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }


  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }


  public String getUrl() {
    return url;
  }

  public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

}
```

But I would like to have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fiche")
public class Fiche {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "TYPE", length = 250, nullable = false)
    private String type;

    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "URL", length = 250, nullable = false)
    private String url;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    
}
```

Is it possible to do that ? Thanks for help

**/////// EDIT POST: ///////**

I have tried this doc
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/persistence-tool-window.html#run-queries

Here’s how I did it:
1/ right-click to the table and select **Generate Persistence Mapping**
2/ Create package and persistenceUnit like this.

[image]

Comment: Please try this instead: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/persistence-tool-window.html#generate_entities_and_mappings.